# Counting and sorting from mysql/php

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, count

I have a MySQL database with user inputted address's in it and need to sort and echo/print in order of the amount of times an address is used/displayed in the database? i.e if an address is in the database more times, then it is to be displayed first, and the least times is to be displayed last in a  environment.

There is no example of coding at this stage, because it is a new script and not to sure where to start with it.

Could any one point me in the right direction?

Comment: "*There is no example of coding at this stage*". Then we cannot solve your problem. Create the database first, then ask us how to query it.

Comment: the database is already created with data and used by other scripts. this is a new script where i need to pull specific data from it in a specific order and am unsure how to do it!!

Comment: I think you do not have idea about how stackoverflow works. With such vague question, it is very difficult to provide you correct answer. Please provide enough information and what you are looking for.

Comment: In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: Sounds like a homework question or that you've never written a mysql query before. Perhaps a start with the mysql tutorial in the mysql docs would be a place to start for something as basic as you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks very much for your helpful input @Niagaradad, however, I am fairly familiar with php and mysql, though I am just stuck on this complex query. I thought my question was very specific and understandable

Comment: Please explain what you believe is complex about it. You need a count and an order by clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seams to have done the job!

```
$sqld="SELECT DeliveryName, DeliveryAddress, count(*)
AS alias
FROM rwxoq_jobs
GROUP BY DeliveryAddress
ORDER BY alias DESC";

$resultd = mysqli_query($conn, $sqld);
while($rowd = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultd)) {
        if (strpos($list, $rowd{'DeliveryAddress'}) === false) {
                $list .= $rowd{'DeliveryAddress'}.'|';
                echo $rowd{'DeliveryName'}.'<BR>'.$rowd{'DeliveryAddress'}.'<BR>';
        }
}
```